# Converting and writing list of strings as binary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, io

I'm trying to convert a Python 2.x version of this code:

```
out_chunk = open('out.txt','w+b')
chunks.append(out_chunk) # out_chunk is just a list of strings like ['a', 'b', ...]
out_chunk.writelines(chunk)
```

into Python 3.x version. If I run the above code in Python 3.x directly, I get an error like below, which is expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/es/prog.py", line 145, in <module>
    ob.external_sort()
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/es/prog.py", line 70, in my_func
    out_chunk.writelines(chunk)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Is there a way to write list of strings as bytes in Python 3.x? Or should I just write as a list of strings (and take the performance hit, maybe?)

Comment: So why is your Python 3 version not producing bytes objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened the file in *binary* mode, so you'd have to encode your bytes.

If you drop the `'b'` part from the file mode (so open with `'w+'` rather than `'w+b'`), you get an implementation of the [`TextIOBase` interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) instead, which will encode strings for you given an encoding (the default is to use the result of `locale.getdefaultencoding()`, you probably want to supply an explicit `encoding` argument to the `open()` call instead).

The alternative would be for you to encode your strings manually, using the [`str.encode()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) on each chunk. Leaving encoding to the `TextIOBase` implementation is going to be a little faster however, because the I/O layer can encode without having to look up a method object on each `str` chunk, nor do the resulting bytes have to be boxed in a Python `bytes` object again.

Also, for encodings that require a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), it is best to leave writing that marker to the file implementation.

However, if you could produce *`bytes` objects* in the first place, you'd avoid having to encode at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't open the file in binary mode:

```
out_chunk = open('out.txt','w+')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. But I wonder if writing a list of string as binary might add some performance gain as opposed to just simply writing them Text I/O. Hopefully, someone who knows Python 3.x IO behavior well might comment here. :) Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Don't worry for such lower case optimization as it could change in a minor Python release. If you have Python3 (unicode) strings and want to write them to a text file, you must first encode them. You can either do explicit encoding and then write to a binary file, or let the TextIO engine do an implicit encoding. Any way, the same encoding have took place so performance should be very close.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: well, the TextIOBase implementation doesn't have to resolve the `.encode` attribute for each chunk, nor push the current frame on the stack to make the call, nor does it have to create the `bytes` object (it can just leave the bytes as a C array to pass on to the wrapped buffer).

Comment: @SergeBallesta: of course, compared to the slow speed of hardware access to a spinning disk that performance difference is going to be insignificant in most cases.

Comment: Thank you guys for insightful answers. I learned more from them! :)